# How do I know whether my function returns a value in C

Tags: c

I wrote a macro which checks whether `calloc` success like

```c
#define CHECK_CALLOC(ptr)                                             \
    if (ptr == NULL)                                                  \
    {                                                                 \
        printf("Error: failed to calloc in %s line %d of func %s.\n", \
               __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);                     \
        return;                                                       \
    }
```

However in some functions that returns a value, I have a warning with GCC saying "warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void". So I'm wondering if there exists something like `argc` that tells me whether my function returns a value. Or can I know whether this function is a void (non-value-returning) function?

```c
#define CHECK_CALLOC(ptr)                                             \
    if (ptr == NULL)                                                  \
    {                                                                 \
        printf("Error: failed to calloc in %s line %d of func %s.\n", \
               __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);                     \
        if (ifReturns)                                                \
            return NULL;                                              \
        else                                                          \
            return;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to call `exit` if an allocation fails.

Comment: @dbush Thank you for comment, but no, I can't ternimate the whole thread.

Comment: use a separate function.

Comment: The naming is off, too. The macro checks a pointer, independent of where it came from. `CHECK_NOT_NULL` would be a better name for it, for example.

Comment: While the idea of checking your memory calls is a good idea, silently returning if memory allocation fails is just ignoring the problem. You're out of memory; there's just going to be more errors.

Comment: Hiding a `return` inside a macro makes the code quite difficult to understand and debug, and it denies the function an opportunity to recover from the error. Better would be to warn and exit, or warn and let the function decide what to do next.

Comment: "can't ternimate" You don't really have a lot of choice. Terminate gracefully, or fail catastrophically. The third option (recover and continue) is an advanced one which you are obviously not prepared to handle yet.

Comment: Please note that such a macro is sub-optimal design and hard to read. The best method when possible, is to first have a wrapper function handling the allocation & allocation errors, then have that one call the actual function.

Comment: "Recover and continue" should be my ultimate target.  Could you give me some keywords I can start with? @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: Suppose you are trying to create a very long linked list, and you exhaust the memory halfway through. What should you do? Obviously not just `return`. The caller won't even know something went wrong. Try writing a small program that handles this situation.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I use `setjmp` and `longjmp` to handle the exception. When run out of memory, I call `longjmp`, free all allocated memory, print error log and then return 1. Is it ok?

Comment: Whatever works for you is OK I guess, but I have no idea how it works together with plain `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variable arguments to specify the return value to use if the function returns a value.

```
#define CHECK_CALLOC(ptr, ...)                                        \
    if (ptr == NULL)                                                  \
    {                                                                 \
        printf("Error: failed to calloc in %s line %d of func %s.\n", \
               __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);                     \
        return __VA_ARGS__;                                           \
    }

void foo()
{
    void *p = calloc(1,1);
    CHECK_CALLOC(p);
}

int bar()
{
    void *p = calloc(1,1);
    CHECK_CALLOC(p,0);
    return 1;
}

void *baz()
{
    void *p = calloc(1,1);
    CHECK_CALLOC(p,NULL);
    return p;
}
```